# How to set the height of table header in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have gone through Apple docs about UITableView class and delegate reference but couldn't find the way to set the table header height explicitly.

I set Table cell height using following delegate:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and set section header/footer height using following delegates.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Could anyone please help me to set the table header/footer height?

Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work if you return 0; but when i return 0.1f it does work for me

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just set the frame property of the tableHeaderView.

Comment: I already do that. I set my image to tableheaderview.I am not able to change table header's height. The thing is HeaderImaze size is 640x88 and it gets rescaled to 320x88 which is wrong so i want to set my table header height to 44 when the specified image resolution width is 640.

Comment: Hi Roger, I think your idea should work. I tried to set frame property using "plainTableView.tableHeaderView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,44);" but nothing happens. Please note that my image size if 640x88 and I am assigning it to tableHeaderView.

Comment: Following worked for me. I couldn't change the table height but I reset the image height.

  
if(headerImage.bounds.size.width == 640)
     [headerImage setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, headerImage.bounds.size.width, headerImage.bounds.size.height/2)];

Answer (score 62):

I found a nice hack. Add the below line after modifying the frame propery

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
```

The trick is (I think) that the UITableView is caching the height (the frame actually) when you assign the view to the tableHeaderView property. The above line just assigns the height again.

Comment: However, if you try to animate the change, it only seems to work in the shrinking direction.

Comment: Animation or not, this is the fastest solution. Perfect :)

Comment: Can't believe this was the solution! It works for making the header smaller & larger. For Swift I'm doing -
    tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView

Answer (score 44):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    sizeHeaderToFit()
}

private func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!

    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = headerView.frame
    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame

    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

More details can be found [here](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/)

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks Kris. Your function still works great in viewDidAppear. It will be better than viewDidLayoutSubviews which is called many times.

Comment: @truongky No, viewDidLayoutSubviews will work eg on rotation or on window resize (eg iPad split screen), what is desired to be resized after it, viewWill/DidAppear will never update it and it will look wrong.

Comment: This is resulting in a freeze due to endless layout loops for me as of iOS 12.4

Answer (score 10):

In case you still need it, have you tried to set the property

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView
```

If you calculate the heigh you need, and set a new view for `tableHeaderView`:

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = newHeight;

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

It should work.

Answer (score 7):

It works with me only if I set the footer/header of the tableview to nil first:

```
self.footer = self.searchTableView.tableFooterView;
CGRect frame = self.footer.frame;
frame.size.height = 200;
self.footer.frame = frame;
self.searchTableView.tableFooterView = nil;
self.searchTableView.tableFooterView = self.footer;
```

Make sure that self.footer is a strong reference to prevent the footer view from being deallocated

Comment: `self.searchTableView.tableFooterView = self.searchTableView.tableFooterView;` works as well.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 - you can manage height with HEIGHT_VIEW,Just add this cods, Its working

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let HEIGHT_VIEW = 60
    tableView.tableFooterView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: tblView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(HEIGHT_VIEW))

    tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size = CGSize(width:tblView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(HEIGHT_VIEW))
}
```

Comment: The best answer

Comment: Good solution, but that "tblView" is a punch in the eye! :'D

Answer (score 2):

Just create Footer Wrapper View using constructor `UIView(frame:_)`
then if you are using xib file for FooterView, create view from xib and add as subView to wrapper view. then assign wrapper to `tableView.tableFooterView = fixWrapper` .

```
    let fixWrapper = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 54)) // dont remove
    let footer = UIView.viewFromNib("YourViewXibFileName") as! YourViewClassName
    fixWrapper.addSubview(footer)
    tableView.tableFooterView = fixWrapper
    tableFootterCostView = footer
```

It works perfectly for me! the point is to create footer view with constructor `(frame:_)`. Even though you create UIView() and assign frame property it may not work.

Answer (score 2):

If add a view as table header view in IB, set the frame of that view in IB in Tab 5(size inspector)

Answer (score 2):

If you programatically set the `tableHeaderView`, then just set it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```swift
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        setupTableViewHeader()
    }

    private func setupTableViewHeader() {
        // Something you do to set it up programatically...
        tableView.tableHeaderView = MyHeaderView.instanceFromNib() 
    }
```

If you didn't set it programatically, you need to do similar to what @Kris answered based on this [link](https://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/)

```swift
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        sizeHeaderToFit()
    }

    private func sizeHeaderToFit() {
        if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
            headerView.setNeedsLayout()
            headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

            let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
            var frame = headerView.frame
            frame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = frame

            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**@kris answer is helpful for me anyone want it in Objective-C.**

**Here is the code**

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
     [self sizeHeaderToFit];
}

-(void)sizeHeaderToFit{
     UIView *headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
     [headerView setNeedsLayout];
     [headerView layoutIfNeeded];
     CGFloat height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
     CGRect frame = headerView.frame;
     frame.size.height = height;
     headerView.frame = frame;
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XIB for tableView's main headerView you can set XIB as a freeform set the Height as you want and unclick Autoresizing's top,bottom blocks and upper,lower arrows.Only horizontal pieces will be selected.Vertical will be unselected as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UIView with the desired height (the width should be that of the UITableView), and inside it you can place a UIImageView with the picture of the proper dimensions: they won't stretch automatically.

You can also give margin above and below the inner UIImageView, by giving a higher height to the container view.

Additionally, you can assign a Translation transform in order to place the image in the middle of its container header view, for example.

Answer (score -1):

If you changed height of tableView's headerView, just reset headerView's frame, then, reset headerView of tableView:

```
self.headerView.frame = newFrame;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
```

Comment: This does so much more than required. Don't use it for such a simple task. Simple setNeedsLayout is enough in case you're describing.

Answer (score -1):

With autolayout you could do something like:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = <your-header-height>
```

or if your headers are of different heights, go ahead and implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return <your-header-height>
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for tableView header, not section header ;)

Answer (score -1):

In Xcode 10 you can set header and footer of section hight from "Size Inspector" tab

[image: Size Inspector header]

Answer (score -2):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
}
```

or you can use like this also

```
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight
```

Comment: We aren't discussing about SEction header. it is about tableView header

Comment: I use the section header and footer as headers and footers for the table. So this is valid for me and was helpful. I found it easier than the other solutions.

Answer (score -3):

Use table view default property :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 35.0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I tried it. It changes the size for section header/footer only not for table header/footer. Am I missing something?

Comment: We aren't discussing about SEction header. it is about tableView header