# If no Table View results, display "No Results" on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a `tableview`, where sometimes there might not be any results to list, so I **would like to put something up that says "no results"** if there are no results (either a label or one table view cell?).

Is there an easiest way to do this?

*I would try a `label` behind the `tableview` then hide one of the two based on the results, but since I'm working with a `TableViewController` and not a normal `ViewController` I'm not sure how smart or doable that is.*

I'm also using `Parse` and subclassing as a `PFQueryTableViewController`:

```
@interface TableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController
```

I can provide any additional details needed, just let me know!

**`TableViewController` Scene in Storyboard:**

[image]

**EDIT:** Per Midhun MP, here's the code I'm using

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
    if ([self.stringArray count] > 0)
    {
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections                 = 1;
        //yourTableView.backgroundView   = nil;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        UILabel *noDataLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
        noDataLabel.text             = @"No data available";
        noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
        noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        //yourTableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
        //yourTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }

    return numOfSections;
}
```

And here's the View I'm getting, it still has separator lines.  I get the feeling that this is some small change, but I'm not sure why separator lines are showing up?

[image]

Comment: I think the trick was to setup empty footerView on tableview to get rid of lines.

Comment: @Andy What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do not use the solution added to this question. Table view data source methods must never do more than they are supposed to do. `numberOfSections` should return a count and that is it. Same for `numberOfRowsInSection`. These can be called many times at any time. Never update views or update data or do anything except return a count. The logic for updating views must never be in these methods.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by using `backgroundView` property of `UITableView`.

**Objective C:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger numOfSections = 0;
    if (youHaveData)
    {
        yourTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        numOfSections                = 1;
        yourTableView.backgroundView = nil;
    }
    else
    {   
        UILabel *noDataLabel         = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourTableView.bounds.size.width, yourTableView.bounds.size.height)];
        noDataLabel.text             = @"No data available";
        noDataLabel.textColor        = [UIColor blackColor];
        noDataLabel.textAlignment    = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        yourTableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel;
        yourTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }

    return numOfSections;
}
```

**Swift:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    var numOfSections: Int = 0
    if youHaveData
    {
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        numOfSections            = 1
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
    }
    else
    {
        let noDataLabel: UILabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.text          = "No data available"
        noDataLabel.textColor     = UIColor.black
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel
        tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
    }
    return numOfSections
}
```

---

Reference [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView)

> `backgroundView` Property
>
> The background view of the table view.
>
> #### Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> `var backgroundView: UIView?`
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *backgroundView`
>
> #### Discussion
>
> A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the
> size of the table view. This view is placed as a subview of the table
> view behind all cells, header views, and footer views.
>
> You must set this property to nil to set the background color of the
> table view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Does this mean I need a `tableView` outlet so that I can do `yourTableView.backgroundView`?  I'm using a `TableViewController` so I don't have an outlet for it right now, thats why I'm wondering.

Comment: `UITableViewController` already has a property named `tableView` so you don't need to create one

Comment: Got it, using `self.tableView`

Comment: I'm still getting separator lines, any idea why?  Thanks!

Comment: @SRMR: Did you set `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` as seperatorStyle ?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer to show the code I have now and screenshot. See anything funky that I'm missing?

Comment: @SRMR: I checked the code by creating a new project (using Master-Detail template provided in XCode). And it is working perfectly. Probably you are having some settings in storyboard, that is causing the issue

Comment: For some reason, I am unable to set the backgroundView or backgroundColor of my UITableView and have it show up. I have tried everything that can be tried with code, thinking it's a Storyboard issue.

Comment: Should we not instantiate `UILabel` class once at `viewDidAppear` when the table view is measured on the screen?

Comment: Working perfect. However, when deleting a row I was getting an error. In the else portion I set numOfSections = 0. Solved my crashing error.

Comment: This code will not work like this it will crash when return have number of rows less than 1. I will edit the code.

Comment: @KeghamK.That crash is not happened by this code. If there is no row available after a deletion, you should use reloadData, instead of deleterowatindexpath.

Comment: @ChrisOSX: I'm wondered why that helped you. Because we are initialised the numOfSections to 0 and if it won't enter to the if block the value will be 0. So again setting it to 0 in else won't make any difference. I think you should check my previous comment, I assume that is the reason for your crash. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: Correction. Upon further testing, I actually had to make that line I mentioned return the same value. numOfSections = 1. If I make it zero and my table view is empty, it works, but when I create a cell and then delete it, instead of deleting and showing the message, it crashes with the following error. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'. I don't know why returning the same value works, but it does and works how it should.

Comment: Do not use this solution. Table view data source methods must never do more than they are supposed to do. `numberOfSections` should return a count and that is it. Same for `numberOfRowsInSection`. These can be called many times at any time. Never update views or update data or do anything except return a count. The logic for updating views must never be in these methods.

Comment: @rmaddy Then can you please answer the question ? Also could you please share the official document which mentions the above mentioned points ? Could you please let me know the scenarios in which the `numberOfSections` can be called multiple times (Other than calling reload data)?

Comment: @rmaddy which is the prettier way? using backgroundView or subclassing a cell class for showing no data?

Answer (score 111):

**For Xcode 8.3.2 - Swift 3.1**

Here is a not-so-well-known but incredibly easy way to achieve adding a "No Items" view to an empty table view that goes back to Xcode 7. I'll leave it to you control that logic that adds/removes the view to the table's background view, but here is the flow for and Xcode (8.3.2) storyboard:

1. Select the scene in the Storyboard that has your table view.
2. Drag an empty UIView to the "Scene Dock" of that scene

[image]

3. Add a UILabel and any constraints to the new view and then create an IBOutlet for that view

[image]

4. Assign that view to the tableView.backgroundView

[image]

5. Behold the magic!

[image]

Ultimately this works anytime you want to add a simple view to your view controller that you don't necessarily want to be displayed immediately, but that you also don't want to hand code.

Comment: This technique works for anything that you need a simple view for. I've also used it for custom table section headers. Really, you can use it for anything that you need a view for. Just reference via an IBOutlet and add it as subview anywhere you need a custom view.

Comment: As @gmogames said, after doing IOS for 2 years this is the first time know about tableView background !. thanks man

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to put it out there, I had to use tableView.separatorStyle  = .none and resize the default UIView to see the backgroundView. I am using Xcode 9.4 with Swift 4.

Comment: How do you place the custom view?

Comment: @Nol4635 In the case of the tableview background, you just assign the view you created as an IBOutlet to the tableview's background or, if you just want to add the view to any another view, you can just add it as a subview. You'll have to set the frame values, but it is like any other view.

Answer (score 30):

Swift Version of above code :-

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    var numOfSection: NSInteger = 0

    if CCompanyLogoImage.count > 0 {

        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        numOfSection = 1


    } else {

        var noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.text = "No Data Available"
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 176.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel

    }
    return numOfSection
}
```

But If you are loading Information From a JSON , you need to check whether the JSON is empty or not , therefor if you put code like this it initially shows "No data" Message then disappear. Because after the table reload data the message hide. So You can put this code where load JSON data to an array. SO :-

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func extract_json(data:NSData) {


    var error: NSError?

    let jsonData: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error)
    if (error == nil) {
        if let jobs_list = jsonData as? NSArray
        {
            if jobs_list.count == 0 {

                var noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
                noDataLabel.text = "No Jobs Available"
                noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 106.0/255.0, blue: 176.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
                noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel

            }

            for (var i = 0; i < jobs_list.count ; i++ )
            {
                if let jobs_obj = jobs_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    if let vacancy_title = jobs_obj["VacancyTitle"] as? String
                    {
                        CJobTitle.append(vacancy_title)

                        if let vacancy_job_type = jobs_obj["VacancyJobType"] as? String
                        {
                            CJobType.append(vacancy_job_type)

                            if let company_name = jobs_obj["EmployerCompanyName"] as? String
                            {
                                CCompany.append(company_name)

                                    if let company_logo_url = jobs_obj["EmployerCompanyLogo"] as? String
                                    {
                                        //CCompanyLogo.append("http://google.com" + company_logo_url)

                                        let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com" + company_logo_url )
                                        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)
                                        if data != nil {
                                            CCompanyLogoImage.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                                        }

                                        if let vacancy_id = jobs_obj["VacancyID"] as? String
                                        {
                                            CVacancyId.append(vacancy_id)

                                        }

                                    }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    do_table_refresh();


}

func do_table_refresh() {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return
    })
}
```

Comment: This works very well for displaying the label when no data is in the rows. However, what is the best way to handle when data does come in and `self.tableView.reloadData()` is called? I've found that it is adding my new rows, but the `noDataLabel` is still displayed underneath them.

Comment: If you array has item just set self.tableView.backgroundView = nil

Comment: if jobs_list.count == 0 { // add above given code } else { self.tableView.backgroundView = nil }

Comment: perfect. adding `self.tableView.backgroundView = nil` in my if statement before `return jobs_list.count`  works well. thanks

Comment: Do not use the first solution in this answer. Table view data source methods must never do more than they are supposed to do. `numberOfSections` should return a count and that is it. Same for `numberOfRowsInSection`. These can be called many times at any time. Never update views or update data or do anything except return a count. The logic for updating views must never be in these methods.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this control. Its is pretty neat. [DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet)

Or if I were you all I would do is

- Check to see if your data array is empty
- If it is empty then add one object called @"No Data" to it
- Display that string in cell.textLabel.text

Easy peasy

Answer (score 6):

**Swift3.0**

*I hope it server your purpose......
In your UITableViewController .*

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        if filteredContacts.count > 0 {
            self.tableView.backgroundView = .none;
            return filteredContacts.count
        } else {
            Helper.EmptyMessage(message: ConstantMap.NO_CONTACT_FOUND, viewController: self)
            return 0
        }
    } else {
        if contacts.count > 0 {
            self.tableView.backgroundView = .none;
            return contacts.count
        } else {
            Helper.EmptyMessage(message: ConstantMap.NO_CONTACT_FOUND, viewController: self)
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

**Helper Class with function :**

```
 /* Description: This function generate alert dialog for empty message by passing message and
           associated viewcontroller for that function
           - Parameters:
            - message: message that require for  empty alert message
            - viewController: selected viewcontroller at that time
         */
        static func EmptyMessage(message:String, viewController:UITableViewController) {
            let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewController.view.bounds.size.width, height: viewController.view.bounds.size.height))
            messageLabel.text = message
            let bubbleColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(57)/255, green: CGFloat(81)/255, blue: CGFloat(104)/255, alpha :1)

            messageLabel.textColor = bubbleColor
            messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            messageLabel.textAlignment = .center;
            messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 18)
            messageLabel.sizeToFit()

            viewController.tableView.backgroundView = messageLabel;
            viewController.tableView.separatorStyle = .none;
        }
```

Comment: Do not use this solution. Table view data source methods must never do more than they are supposed to do. `numberOfSections` should return a count and that is it. Same for `numberOfRowsInSection`. These can be called many times at any time. Never update views or update data or do anything except return a count. The logic for updating views must never be in these methods.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 (updated):

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if myArray.count > 0 {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        return 1
    }

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                      y: 0,
                      width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                      height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height)
    let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)

    noDataLabel.text = "Custom message."
    noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    noDataLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    self.tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Do not use this solution. Table view data source methods must never do more than they are supposed to do. `numberOfSections` should return a count and that is it. Same for `numberOfRowsInSection`. These can be called many times at any time. Never update views or update data or do anything except return a count. The logic for updating views must never be in these methods.

Comment: I agree. This solution can be improved, but it also can be used.

Comment: How can you agree that you should not use this solution but then state that is can also be used? That's a contradiction.

Comment: I agree that this solution can be improved, but, in its current state, will also work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most elegant way to solve your problem is switching from a `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView`. This way you can add whatever `UIView` you want as subviews of the main view.

I wouldn't recommend using a UITableViewCell to do this you might need to add additional things in the future and things can quicky get ugly.

You can also do something like this, but this isn't the best solution either.

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview: OverlayView];
```

Comment: Thanks for the color around which is most elegant way to implement, always a good way to think about it.  I might try changing my storyboard to use a `UIViewController` containing a `UITableView`.

Comment: That's the most future-proof way. I have never used a `UITableViewController` myself, because using it isn't really much easier than doing it the other way, yet it limits your ability to change things in the future.

Comment: This is not future-proof if you have translucent bars. I highly recommend against.  At the very least, make a UIViewController that contains a UITableViewController and adjusts things appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in Your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method:-

```
if ([array count]==0
{

    UILabel *fromLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 300, 60)];                                                                                        
    fromLabel.text =@"No Result";
    fromLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
    fromLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    fromLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    fromLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    [fromLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:Embrima size:30.0f]];
    [self.view addSubview:fromLabel];
    [self.tblView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do not use this solution. Table view data source methods must never do more than they are supposed to do. `numberOfSections` should return a count and that is it. Same for `numberOfRowsInSection`. These can be called many times at any time. Never update views or update data or do anything except return a count. The logic for updating views must never be in these methods.

Answer (score 2):

I would present a an overlay view that has the look and message you want if the tableview has no results. You could do it in ViewDidAppear, so you have the results before showing/not showing the view.

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 3

```
        let noDataLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.text             = "No data available"
        noDataLabel.textColor        = UIColor.white
        noDataLabel.font             = UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 15)
        noDataLabel.textAlignment    = .center
        tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

1. Add the following code to a new file.
2. Change your table class to the custom class "MyTableView" from storyboard or .xib

(this will work for the first section only. If you want to customize more, do changes in the MyTableView reloadData() function accordingly for other sections)

```
public class MyTableView: UITableView {

    override public func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()

        if self.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) == 0 {
            if self.viewWithTag(1111) == nil {
                let noDataLabel = UILabel()
                noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
                noDataLabel.text = "No Data Available"
                noDataLabel.tag = 1111
                noDataLabel.center = self.center
                self.backgroundView = noDataLabel
            }

        } else {
            if self.viewWithTag(1111) != nil {
                self.backgroundView = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach. I've added some enhancement as following to make it more well rounded.

1. Cache separator style of tableview and restore it upon empty/non-empty state transition to make this subclass applicable for use cases which different  separator styles are desired.
2. Add `@IBInspectable var emptyStateText: String?` and mark this class as `@IBDesignable` then you will be able to change different empty state text for different scenes in storyboard or xibs. Enjoy! :)

Comment: This code assumes there is only one section in the table view.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the tableview footer and do not want the tableview to fill up the screen with empty default table cells i would suggest that you set your tableview footer to an empty UIView. I do not know the correct syntax for doing this in obj-c or Swift, but in Xamarin.iOS i would do it like this:

```
public class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITableView _table;

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated) {
        // Initialize table

        _table.TableFooterView = new UIView();
    }
}
```

Above code will result in a tableview without the empty cells

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in one file and change your collection type to CustomCollectionView

```
import Foundation

class CustomCollectionView: UICollectionView {

  var emptyModel = EmptyMessageModel()
  var emptyView: EmptyMessageView?
  var showEmptyView: Bool = true

  override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()

    emptyView?.removeFromSuperview()
    self.backgroundView = nil

    if !showEmptyView {
      return
    }

    if numberOfSections < 1 {
      let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        width: self.bounds.size.width,
                        height: self.bounds.size.height)

      emptyView = EmptyMessageView()
      emptyView?.frame = rect
      if let emptyView = emptyView {
        //                self.addSubview(emptyView)
        self.backgroundView = emptyView
      }
      emptyView?.setView(with: emptyModel)

    } else {
      emptyView?.removeFromSuperview()
      self.backgroundView = nil
    }
  }
}

class EmptyMessageView: UIView {

  @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

  var view: UIView!

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
  }

  func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    view.frame = bounds

    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
  }

  func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "EmptyMessageView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
  }

  func setView(with model: EmptyMessageModel) {
    messageLabel.text = model.message ?? ""
    imageView.image = model.image ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_notification")
  }
}

///////////
class EmptyMessageModel {
  var message: String?
  var image: UIImage?

  init(message: String = "No data available", image: UIImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "no_notification")) {
    self.message = message
    self.image = image
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without any code, try this!

Click on your tableView.

[image: tableView Screenshot]

Change the style from "plain" to "grouped".

[image: Table View properties screenshot-2]

Now when you use ....

tableView.backgroundView = INSERT YOUR LABEL OR VIEW

It will not show the separators!

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here require you to add ui code to `numberOfSections` TableView extension, which you should really avoid doing. Instead, here is a Swift 5 solution that works just as well.

1. Add a Class variable `let noDataLabel = UILabel()` and add it as a subview to your View:

   ```
    noDataLabel.text = "no data string"
    noDataLabel.textColor = .white
    noDataLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
    noDataLabel.isHidden = true
    noDataLabel.layer.zPosition = 2
    noDataLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(noDataLabel)
   ```

Just to be sure, you can set its zPosition to be one above your TableView. Your label should be set to `isHidden = true`.
Don't forget to set `translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and add the necessary constraints:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    //Fill Screen
    tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    tableView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    //Center
    noDataLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    noDataLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    noDataLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
])
```

That's pretty much it! Now, inside of your update() function (called when you refresh your tableView for example, or whenever you try to load data), add the following lines of code:

```
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        if dataArray.isEmpty {
            noDataLabel.isHidden = false
        }else{
            noDataLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
```

Be sure to add your `if else` just below your tableView `reloadData` function.