# Single tab bar item present different view controllers depending on a condition?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am making an app that has a couple of different tabs using a tab bar controller.  I add items to a bag in the first tab, and update the cart in the next viewcontroller.  If the user goes to the second tab (the cart) without adding anything I want it to present a view controller saying the cart is empty.  If they go to it once they have added something then it will show a table view.

Is there any way to tell a tab bar controller to present different view controllers depending on a condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is to use one `CartViewController`, whose view has two subviews, a table view (A) with the cart items and another view (B) with the 'cart is empty' message.

Override its `viewWillAppear` function, and depending on the cart, show view A and hide view B or vice versa.

You *can* modify the child view controllers of a `UITabBarController`, via the [`viewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621185-viewcontrollers) property. However, doing this by reacting on changes in the cart is complicated an not worth the trouble, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks that's what I ended up doing, I think it's the simplest solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually present the same `UITableViewController`.
In that `UITableViewController` you must be knowing whether you have data or not. If you have a data for `UITableViewController` then you will show the items in cart in `UITableViewController` else you can have empty message in the same `UITableViewController`.
You can refer this post to show empty message on `UITableViewController?

[If no Table View results, display "No Results" on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532926/if-no-table-view-results-display-no-results-on-screen) .