# Migrate UITableViewController to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a UITableViewController, but would like to add a label at the bottom of the screen. I think the easiest way to do this would be to just use a UIViewController with a UITableView. Is there an easy way to migrate over? I've noticed some functionally is different; for example UITableViewController has a `numberOfSections` method, whereas UITableView does not have that method. Also is it possible to use a UIViewController as the delegate for a UITableView? Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have attached a picture of the code, and the error given when trying to implement UITableViewDataSource.

[image: Source Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. You need to implement the UITableViewDelegate and include the UITableViewDatasource in your View Controller, then you can use the functions you were using in your TableViewController.

Basically what you should do is add a tableview in the interface builder, or programmatically (depending on your choice). If it's done through the interface builder then outlet it to your Controller. Add the Delegate to your class, and you would have access to the tableViewFunctions (cellForRow, numberOfItems, numberOfSections, didSelectRow etc...).

Also, when you create the tableview specify the tableview.delegate = self and tableview.datasource = self.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the methods are the same, you just won't need the `override` bit before each one if its just a `UITableView`. You can use `UIViewController` as the delegate, yes, by setting `myTableView.delegate = self` in its `viewDidLoad` method.

If its just a label you need however, you might consider adding one programatically? Similar results achieved with a no data label for example - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532926/if-no-table-view-results-display-no-results-on-screen). You could then play around with the positioning.

Comment: Hi, I cannot adopt the UITableViewDelegate as a UIViewController, so the methods won't transfer over.

Comment: Have you added the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols to the class declaration? Perhaps you could update the original question with your code?

Comment: Hi Tom, please see the updated question, which now has a picture of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because you need to set `dataSource` to your `TableView` Object like `self.tableView.dataSource = self`. After this you can use freely all methods for `UITableView` including `numberOfSections` as you mentioned.