# Empty tableview label flashes for a second if there is data in my array

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Hi I have searched stack overflow and saw [If no Table View results, display "No Results" on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532926/if-no-table-view-results-display-no-results-on-screen/32708294?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
 which is useful but not exactly what i am looking for.
My problem is when i follow these steps it works correctly. but if my tableview does end up having data it will flash my "empty tableview label" for a second or 2 before populating my data. It looks terrible in my opinion.

I have a label connected through outlet on my tableview called emptyTableViewlbl. This is my code being called in. Thanks in advance any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if posts.isEmpty {
        emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden = false
        emptyTableViewLbl.text = "Empty tableview label"
        return 0
    } else {
        emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden = true
    }
    return posts.count

}
```

and have tried

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    loadPosts()

    if posts.isEmpty {
        emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden = false
        emptyTableViewLbl.text = "Empty"
    } else {
        emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `numberOfRowsInSection` must not do anything except return a count. It can be called any number of times and at any time. Never update any views or anything else except return a number.

Comment: The correct place to show the "empty" label is when `loadPosts` completes with no posts found.

Comment: Thankyou @rmaddy for clarifying that considering almost every tutorial/post was saying to check through the numberOfRowsInSection. Can you please give us the correct solution for solving this. Im sure it will help a lot of people thanks!

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for getting back to me although that makes sense. I do not know if my loadPosts actually has data until it called. Therefore my condition never gets checked.

Comment: The comment by @Paulw11 gives the proper solution. Update your "empty" label in `loadPosts` based on the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didSet` to do so

suppose your array is

```
var posts:[Post] {
  didSet {
     if posts.isEmpty {
        emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden = false
    } else {
        emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden = true
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
    tableview.isHidden =  !emptyTableViewLbl.isHidden
  }

}
```