# Display welcome message in chat

Tags: ios, swift3, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I wander how to display **`welcome message`** in center of chat before **`first message`**?

 I search in this point but not get answer.

Comment: just add a label on centre of your view on first launch of chat window and hide this label as soon as chat intitiated. By the way what u did before asking this question. plz show ur code.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642883/3901620