# How to adjust the height of my tableView when my dropdown menu is clicked?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drop-down-menu

I have a implemented a drop down menu above my UITableView and when I click on it I want my table view to go down inside the items of my drop down menu, because right now when I click on my drop down menu, the tableview stay where it is..

i have a view above my prototype cell that contain my drop down menu but I can't put any constraints on it... when I click in "filtre" I want this to happen : [image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN6Tz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you added a Table Header view. it is a little different than common UIView.

Instead of changing Height constraints, you'd better to change the frame of the headerview

[how-to-set-the-height-of-table-header-in-uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581116/how-to-set-the-height-of-table-header-in-uitableview)

In addition, you can found good codes of dropdown implementation from these links.
https://github.com/qmathe/DropDownMenuKit

https://github.com/onmyway133/Dropdowns

Comment: oh yeah I see thanks, but do you know what is the property I need to change to make this header view start lower or upper in the screen?

Comment: let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!
    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = headerView.frame
    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView


You can call this method on viewDidlayoutsubviews method.