# How to increase and decrease UIView height by codebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I have to add `UIView` in top of the `Tableview` but it should be inside Tableview because of `scrolling`. Here, I drag and dropped UIView on `topside` tableview. Now, some scenario I need to `increase` and reduce `height` of the UIView. I tried to add `constraints` but its not available. How to achieve this by codebase?

**Tableview with UIView Storyboard Hierarchy**

[image]

**Storyboard Design**

[image]

**Disabled Constraints For UIView**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Constraints` is not working with table header view. you can set table header using custom view and update its frame

Set a custom view

[image]

Set table header and update it's frame

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var tableHeader: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        loadHeader()
    }

    func loadHeader() {
        tableHeader.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 300)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy. I will try and update you here. is there anything possibilities to adjust height because in that way we designed UI.

Comment: this is ok but how can I  change automatic tableHeader height after any specific task ??

Comment: you can call loadHeader once again

Comment: Please check this answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/5581116/5461400